# Genexus .Net Generator

Tags: asp.net, genexus

I am trying to migrate an old aspx site that was built using GeneXus .Net Generator. Looking at the `web.config` I see keys with database connection information but it is encrypted

```
<add key="Connection-Default-User" value="******" />
<add key="Connection-Default-Password" value="*******" />
```

I don't know how to generate those encrypted values. Googling, the only place I saw someone referencing to those keys was this page: [Web Model - .NET Generator Manual of GeneXus X](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?9835).

Here is a sample value (from that page):

```
<add key="Connection-Default-User" value="Elj20MqY44RPdvT8FEpDD0==" />
```

But no details on it.

Any help on knowing how to generate those encrypted values is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your generated applications's `bin` folder, there is an utility called `GxConfig.exe`. When you run it, if it finds the `web.config` file it will modify it, otherwise it will create a new one (you may need to copy the file from your web server).

You can find more information in the [GxConfig page from the Community Wiki](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?14912).

Quoting that page:

> In order to configure the database access parameters in production,
>   the Gxconfig tool is provided for each datastore.
>
> It allows specifying a database Name, server, user password included
>   in the web.config file (web environment) or Client.exe.config file
>   (win environment and reorganization). The username and password are
>   encrypted in the same way as it is done in the GeneXus environment.